# getting vi and rxvt to work in cygwin

Tags: cygwin, vi

I am trying to use rxvt on my cygwin w win XP but the terminal appears and disappears. What could be wrong? This is true for all except rxvt-native . I have tried a few commands found online but with no success. I include 2 I have tried:

```
start C:\cygwin\bin\rxvt.exe -sb -sl 3000 -fg gray -bg black -fn "Lucida Console-14" -e /bin/bash --login -i
```

.

```
path C:\cygwin\bin;%path%
ssh-agent rxvt -e bash --login -i
```

Another problem I am facing is trying to get vi to work in my cygwin bash shell. Setting term to xterm or vt100 does not work. Hitting enter, I see a string 78 or some other issue pops up. I have never modified my .inputrc.

My main issue was trying to get vi to work properly. I just found out that if I run 
/etc/postinstall/terminfo.sh.done , I can now navigate properly in vi. The 78 (newline) M still appears but at least I can navigate in vi.

Feb 25 - This problem went away after a few windows updates. Would it make sense to ANSWER my question on the basis that this is longer reproducible?

Comment: You'll need to run Xming to see those rxvt's come up if they aren't -native. Those are the ones that use X11. Windows doesn't have it natively, so you'll need Xming. Same with the gvim binary.

You can alternatively just get gvim for windows.

Comment: @Tom Plain 'rxvt' runs without requiring X unless the DISPLAY variable is set. And anyway, Cygwin has its own X server, so Xming is not necessarily required.

@sunyata Where are you invoking rxvt from? Do you have an X server running?

Comment: Are you using `vim` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing which may not have been clear was that the whole exercise was to get vi to work. vim did not work either at that time. But after some windows update, the problem went away. Closing it...

Answer (score 0):

Can't answer the first question, but have you tried invoking rxvt from its shortcut in the Cygwin folder of the start menu?

Regarding the second question, the TERM variable tells applications what terminal they're running in, so if you set it to 'xterm' while running in the Cygwin console (where normally TERM=cygwin), they'll be sending xterm control sequences that the Cygwin console doesn't understand. So basically: don't do that!

Btw, you might also be interested in Cygwin's mintty package, which is another terminal that doesn't need an X server. Installing it also creates a start menu shortcut in the Cygwin folder.

Answer (score 0):

I would assume you need an X server running.
You could install [Cygwin/X](http://x.cygwin.com/)

Comment: rxvt doesn't require Cygwin/X.